# How to select the host in Ansible depending on the value of a variable?

Tags: ansible, host

I want to use the answer provided by the user to select the hosts in an Ansible playbook, like the following pseudocode:

```yaml
---   
- name: feed the machines

  vars_prompt:
    - name: food
      prompt: "Which food do you have? b:Banana, g:grass, m:meat."
      default: "b"
      private: no

  hosts: 'monkeys' if food=='b' else {'cows' if food=='g' else 'lions'}
```

I am aware that using a dictionary would also be an option.

How do I implement it? It would be nice to have answers with `if`s or with a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to template the `hosts` parameter with the correct Jinja expression, so an [inline-if](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#if-expression):

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ 'monkeys' if food=='b' else 'cows' if food=='g' else 'lions' }}"
  gather_facts: no

  vars_prompt:
    - name: food
      prompt: "Which food do you have? b:Banana, g:grass, m:meat."
      default: "b"
      private: no
```

Which would yield:

```
Which food do you have? b:Banana, g:grass, m:meat. [b]: 

PLAY [monkeys] ***************************************************************

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************
```

---

The same with a dictionary that would make a food correspond to an animal:

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ food_to_animal[food] }}"
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    food_to_animal:
      b: monkeys
      g: cows
      m: lions

  vars_prompt:
    - name: food
      prompt: "Which food do you have? b:Banana, g:grass, m:meat."
      default: "b"
      private: no
```